# Glossy BSDF not found in Blender 2.79 Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Simple (and may be stupid) question - how to include (if it should be included or plugget in) Glossy BSDF in my Blender 2.79?

I'm follow a manual video ([this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=34&v=sz0VdShyii0)), where user just input "glos" in Cycles search and Glossy BSDF appears at search result.

So, I can't repeat that because can't find Glossy BSDF by search menu (look at screenshot below).

Please, help!

Thank you!

[image: screenshot: Cycles -> Shift + A -> input glossy -> found nothing]

Comment: Cycles? - You have Blender Render active.

Comment: Thank You, @michaelh! It's my first experience with rendering with node editor. So, please, may You tell me - what should I do to get a glossy BSDF? As I understand now, I have a mistake - open Blender Render. My bad. What should I open to?

Comment: You have the wrong render Engine activated. You are not using Cycles, but Blender Internal (Blender Render). That is why you don't see the Glossy Shader. Look at the top center dropdown. - Change it from Blender Render to Cycles and you're good to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing "Blender render" to "Cycles render".

[image: click there]

click at the region pointed, and select the render engine "Cycles render".

[image]

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your answer, like a screenshot to show how to change the render engine?

Comment: In the top header there it shows in the OP that 'Blender Render' is indicated - this is where to choose 'Cycles Render' instead.

Comment: @ScottMilner click at the region pointed, and select the render engine "Cycles render"